# How do I deliver my bundle.js file with my html in GO using gorilla/mux

Tags: reactjs, go

I am trying to make a simple server with a Go backend and React frontend. To do this, I need to send my static html and bundle.js file. Her's the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/48938155eb24b4ccdde09426066869504c6dab3c/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <title>Mern Gen</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<main id='root'>
  App has crashed
</main>
<script src="../public/bundle.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I am doing this to deliver both files to the '/' url

```
bs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
http.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", bs))

fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
http.Handle("/", fs)
```

I now need to use gorilla/mux to match variable parameters like this

```
r.HandleFunc("/loc/{id}", getLoc)
```

But if I do that I have to also change from the default mux to the gorilla router

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
bs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
r.Handle("/public/", http.StripPrefix("/public/", bs))

fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
r.Handle("/", fs)
```

And this does not work. I get an error saying that my bundle.js is not found. How do I do this with gorilla mux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `PathPrefix` for serving files in the `public` directory:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()

bs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
r.PathPrefix("/public/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/public/", bs))

fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))
r.Handle("/", fs)

http.Handle("/", r)
```

Refer to [Gorilla mux document](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux)